# Is this topology stronger than the cofinite topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the real numbers. Is the following topology *stronger* than the cofinite topology? And is $X$ then compact?

$T = \{ U \subset\mathbb{R}\:|\:0\notin U\text{ or }\mathbb{R}\setminus U\text{ finite}\} $

Comment: What is $X$? How does finiteness of $X\setminus \mathbb R$ affect $U$? What is a compact topology? It is homework?

Comment: And does "stronger" mean having *more* or *less* open sets?

Comment: More open sets.. Because now you have finite open sets right? Every   set without $0$ belongs to the topology (along with all cofinite sets).

Comment: @Chris: Where have you seen it used to mean fewer open sets?

Comment: @Brian: Wikipedia claims that "there are some authors, especially analysts, who use the terms weak and strong with opposite meaning", citing Munkres as evidence. I haven't actually seen this myself, but I thought it best to check.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I like this "especially analysts"! I always knew one shall be careful with these people

Comment: Back in the old days, I was told that in the term "CW Complex", the "W" stands for "weak topology" which (unfortunately) means having as many open sets as possible subject to agreeing with the standard topology on each of the simplices.

Comment: @GEdgar: perhaps, due to the reason that it provides the weakest condition for function to be continuous?

Comment: Having more open sets, or having more continuous functions, or having more convergent sequences ... which should be rewarded by being called "stronger"?

Comment: The terminology used is usually 'finer' and 'coarser' rather than 'stronger' and 'weaker'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write this as the union of the cofinite topology and the union of all sets not containing $0$, so it is stronger. It is also compact. Every open covering must contain an element containing $0$ and this element will have a finite complement. Supply the details yourself.

Comment: So the proof that the above given space X is compact would be:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an opencover of $X$, then there exists a $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ which contains $0$ such that $X\setminus{U_0}$ is finite. Then, for every  $x \in X\setminus{U_0}$ there is a $U_x \in \mathcal{U}$ containing x. The union $U_0 \cup \{U_x : x \in X\setminus{U_0} \}$ is a finite open cover of X. So X is compact.

Comment: @omar Exactly.${}$